# General formula for $\det(A+I)$ where I is identity. Worked it out for $2 \times 2$ and $3 \times 3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does anybody know a general formula for $|A+I|$ where $A$ is a $\textbf{symmetric}$, real (square) matrix?

For a $2\times2$ system I worked out:
$|A+I| = |A|+\text{tr}(A)+1$. This is very friendly.

For a $3\times3$ system I worked out:
$|A+I| = |A|+\text{tr}(A) + 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{3} |M_{i,i}|$, where $M_{i,i}$ is the determinant of the i,i-th minor, i.e. the determinant of the matrix that ensues when we remove the i-th row and i-th column from the original matrix $A$.

Now, I am wondering (and assuming) that this problem is not new and was wondering if anybody knew of a general formula. Because for a $4\times4$ system, this last formula does not hold.

All your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't think there is any "nice" formula, but you can start here in your search: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial

Comment: I am aware of the characteristic polynomial but I was wondering it be possible to rewrite the problem in terms of the eigenvalues perhaps and then find a pattern? So far, I have gotten stuck though.

Comment: Since $A$ is symmetric if and only if $A+I$ is symmetric, this doesn't seem much different from asking whether there is a general formula for the determinant of a symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an $n \times n$ matrix $A$, it is known (and not too difficult to see) that the coefficient of $\lambda^k$ in the polynomial $\det(I+\lambda A)$ is the sum of the $k \times k$ principal minors of $A$. Call this sum $S_k$; then, for example, $S_1=\operatorname{tr}(A)$ and $S_n=\det(A)$, and your sum involving $M_{i,i}$ is $S_{n-1}$.

Since $\det(I+\lambda A) = 1 + S_1 \lambda + S_2 \lambda^2 + \dots + S_n \lambda^n$, you find by setting $\lambda=1$ that $\det(I+A)=1+S_1+S_2+\dots+S_n$.

This doesn't assume that $A$ is symmetric; I don't think things get much simpler in that particular case.

(By the way, you used the word *minor* for a submatrix, but it's usually taken to mean *subdeterminant*.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! However, I am still a little confused. Your $S_{k} is a summation of the minors (i.e. sub determinants) from 1 through k, right? So, $S_{3}$ for example is a sum involving three elements M_{1,1}, M_{2,2}, and M_{3,3}? Thank you again!

Comment: A $k\times k$ principal minor is obtained by selecting $k$ indices from the set $\{ 1,\dots,n \}$ and forming the determinant of the entries in the rows and colums with those indices. This can be done in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways, so that's the number of terms in the sum $S_k$.